# How do I configure Putty so that I can save the setup?

Tags: putty

I'm using Putty version 0.73.

I'm trying to save my setup configuration but `Save` button does not seem to work.

I have downloaded the latest again and checked the help but nothing specific has been found.

And using Search in Help does not address the issue.

Comment: Dear, which distro, putty for Windows or for Linux?

Answer (score 4):

When you try to save a setup about a session you must complete all information, and before to hit the `Save` button you must write in the `Saved Session` text input the name of your session configuration to save. So you can find in the list below your session, as follow image:

[image: Screenshot of Saved Session with Putty]

I've used puTTy version 0.73 for Windows 64 bit with MSI installer.

Comment: Note that: 1) You can tweak settings, but leave the hostname blank, and save settings, that way you can load that and then decide which host to connect to using those settings. 2) You can overwrite the default settings by using that exact name under Saved Sessions (easier if you load it first, that way PuTTy will load the name for you in the Saved Sessions box.)

Comment: @filbranden: Thanks for your precisation ;)

Comment: Joe Taras method worked